# Maya Python - Loop list elements for splitting

Tags: python, maya

Hi guys I would like to loop multiple elements in a list elements creating a for loop, to make this script work with multi selection.. at the moment I can find an appropriate solution to append each element contained in myStr... Any idea? (at the moment I've added myStr[0] to pick first element)

```
myStr = cmds.ls(sl=1)
for i in myStr:
    splits = myStr[0].split('_')
    ver_up = int(splits[-2]) + 1
    splits[-2] = '%04d'%ver_up
    newStr = '_'.join(splits)
    print(newStr)
   
    cmds.duplicate(n=newStr)
```

Comment: `cmds` is not defined.  what is this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you have several objects with a name based on `<objectName>_<version>_<otherIdentifiers>`. And you want to duplicate them and count up the version number. Correct? If so, you just have to add the object you want to duplicate to the `cmds.duplicate()` command like this:

```
cmds.duplicate(i, n=newStr)
```

Comment: Basically I would like to run this command for every single obj contained in the myStr list, the problem I am facing is in this specific line: `splits = myStr[0].split('_')` is there a way to sort of loop each element of the list in order perform split operation to each element of the list individually?

Comment: instead of `myStr[0]` what references always the very first element in the list, you should use `i.split(('_')`.

Comment: Nice I got this to work!